# Wait by an attribute after a decision split in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'd like to have the following scenario:

If the date value of a field called `FlightDate` is more than e.g. 2 days away, then I would like to wait until the day after (another value) `BookingDate` in order to send an email. Both `FlightDate` and `BookingDate` values are included in the entry point Data Extention of the journey (Journey Data).

I realized that after I create a **Decision Split** activity and set the condition, it is immediately followed by a normal wait activity (**Wait By Duration**) and I cannot replace it with a **Wait By Attribute** activity.

In other words, I would like to have **Wait By Attribute** instead of a 1 day wait in the picture below (blue arrow).

[image]

I am wondering if there's a workaround for this.

Answer (score 3):

> In other words, I would like to have Wait By Attribute instead of a 1
>   day wait in the picture below (blue arrow).

You can just delete this **Wait By Duration** Activity and add a **Wait By Attribute** before the Email Activity.

Update:

Disasterkid, I was able to put a **Wait By Attribute** after the **Decision Split** (The UI allowed me).

[image]

[image]

Maybe you are actually having another problem. Can be either:

1) You are trying first to insert the **Wait By Attribute** after the **Decision Split** (like in the blue arrow in your pic). The problem is **Journey Builder** doesn't allow you to set two *wait activities* one after other (You need to have you Activity between them).

I faced this problem before. I tried to workaround By adding an **Email Activity**, between the **Wait By Attribute** and **Wait By Duration**

*[...] -> Wait By Attribute -> Email Activity -> Wait By Duration -> [...]*

Then remove the **Email Activity**.

*[...] -> Wait By Attribute -> Wait By Duration -> [...]*

The UI will allow this, but when I had gotten an error message when validated the Journey.

So you need to first delete this **Wait By Duration**, then add the **Wait By Attribute**.

2) In your comment you're reporting a problem with moving the **Decision Split**. I think is not possible to move the **Decision Split** to the right, you need to move the other Activities to the left. I have had this problem either.

Comment: Well, that's the point. I cannot move that activity after the decision split. Neither can I replace the wait activity.

Comment: I get a red X when I try to move the *Wait By Attribute* between them.

Comment: I realized it's a bit truícky on Journey Builder. I should first drag the *Wait By Attribute* to the canvas and then drag the *Decision Split* right before it. It doesn't work the other way around. At least here!